# How to differentiate $x\sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus

How could one differentiate $x\sqrt{x}$?

I know $[\sqrt{x}]' = \dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

Comment: Do you know the product rule for derivatives?

Comment: Or you can write $x\sqrt x=x^{\frac 32}$ and use the power law.

Comment: Note the in the answers you have 2 different approaches: (1) $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ and use the *power rule*. (2) $x \times \sqrt{x}$ and use the *product rule*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$, so just differentiate $x^{3/2}$, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}x\sqrt{x}=\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 3):

Product rule: $$(fg)'= f'g + fg'$$

Take $f=x$ and $g=\sqrt x$

You know $f'=1$ so 
$$
(fg)'(x)= \sqrt{x} + \frac{x}{2\sqrt{x}}.
$$